# swift 2 Core Data Predicate case insensitive search set in array

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate, predicate

I have a subclass A with a one to many B relationship. I would like to search an attribute in B case. So i manage to do this but I don't know how to make it case insensitive.

```
Class A{
    @NSManaged var id:String?
    @NSManaged var relationshipToB: NSSet?
}

Class B{
    @NSManaged var someAttribute: String?
}
```

This works but it is case sensitive. how do I make it case insensitive?
Where do i add the [c]?

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "A")
var predicates = [NSPredicate]()
predicates.append(NSPredicate(format:"ANY relationshipToB. someAttribute in  %@", arrayToSearch))
.
.
.
```

I tried adding the "[c]" in almost any position but no luck. Any one have an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Before asking, please search. [Google](https://www.google.de/search?q=Core+Data+Predicate+case+insensitive&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=7LBKWIH5HYje8geUspz4Cg). If the found solustions do not work, please post code of what you have tried "I tried adding the "[c]" in almost any position" and what did not work with those solutions. Further tips can be found in the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
predicates.append(NSPredicate(format:"ANY relationshipToB. someAttribute in [c] %@", arrayToSearch))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but I tried this and it doesn't work. its still case sensitive. Any other ideas maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below code.

```
predicates.append(NSPredicate(format:"ANY mainText. someAttribute in [cd] %@", array))
```